# Ordenar por ano dados SQL

Tags: sql, data, classificação

Tenho uma tabela com 2 colunas (uma com data (AAAA,MM,DD) e outra com um valor numerico). Quero que a tabela fica ordenada apenas por ano e no caso de ter entradas com o mesmo ano o fator de "desempate" ser o valor numerico.
Como posso fazer?

Comment: depende, qual banco de dados está usando? só usar uma função que extraia o ano da data, mas precisa saber qual o banco... seria por exemplo `order by YEAR(coluna), outra_coluna`

Comment: Tenho uma tabela seguro com as colunas apolice, datai e cobertura. Quero uma lista das apolices ordenadas por ano e em caso de "desempate" ordenar pelo valor da cobertura. Experimentei o comando:

Comment: select apolice
from seguro
order by YEAR(datai), cobertura asc; 

Mas dá erro...

Comment: como eu comentei, precisa saber o banco de dados, `year` é uma função para `sql-server`

Comment: Coloque o banco de dados que está utilizando, se possível insira as tabelas utilizadas para melhor entendimento da pergunta :)

Comment: Tenho uma outra questão:
Preciso de uma query que me devolva a marca com maior nº de acidentes. Tenho 3 tabelas que preciso de usar: veiculo, acidente e acid_veic. Cada acidente tem um numero, o n_acid e preciso de ir às tabelas acidente e veic_acid ver quais os veiculos envolvidos em cada acidente.  Na tabela acidente o nº do veiculo acidentado está na coluna "veic_seguro" e  na tabela acid_veic o nº do veiculo acidentado está na coluna "veiculo". Depois tenho de os agrupar por marcas e contar para ver qual deles se repete mais vezes, para assim a query me devolver essa marca

Answer (score 0):

Bom, no Mysql eu faria assim (use como base para outro banco).
A sua consulta deve retornar todos os campos por meio do *, e através da função Year retornar só o ano como um campo.
Nota: Year é uma função do Mysql.

```
SELECT *, Year(data) AS ano FROM nome_da_sua_tabela ORDER BY ano;
```

Comment: dá-me erro de sintaxe em "year". Não sei se ajuda dizer que estou a usar o PUTTY

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está utilizando?

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim, consegui! Obrigada pela ajuda